# Pass php function to linux Variable

Tags: php, linux

In my bash script,I would like to pass the output of a php function to a  linux variable.The php file is returning an array.Here is what I have so far

```
#!/bin/bash
credentials=$(php test.php)
```

But this produces an error.What is the better way to do this?
error:cannot assign list to array member

Comment: **What** error does it produce? Don't make us guess, give us as much information as you have, even if you don't understand it all.

Answer (score 0):

The below works fine for me. The only thing wrong with your script is that you have `#!bin/bash` instead of `#!/bin/bash`.

```
#!/bin/bash
credentials=$(php test.php)
echo $credentials
```